# Memory access violation doesn't give any error in c

Tags: c, gcc, undefined-behavior

I have wrote a simple program as follows.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

int main()
{
    char *a=NULL;
    int i;
    a = malloc(sizeof(char ) *10);
    memset(a,100,'\0');

    if(a == NULL) printf("errr\n");
    for(i=0;i<20;i++)
        a[i]='c';

    printf("%s",a);
    printf("%d",strlen(a));
}
```

Here I allocated only 10 bytes and writing 20 bytes. I compiled the code successfully and run without any segmentation fault

My question is why doesn't it give any segmentation fault here?

Comment: It doesn't have to give you a seg fault, it's simply [undefined behaviour](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub), meaning your program could even appear to 'work'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is, unauthorized (invalid) memory access invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). The outcome is , undefined.

Remember, segmentation fault is ***one of the many*** possible outcomes of UB, not the **only** one.From the code which invokes UB, you cannot expect anything for certain, not even segmentation fault.

That said, for the successful compilation part, there is no syntactical error for the compiler to refuse to compile, so the compilation is a success.

Apart from that, some observation points/ suggestions

- `memset(a,100,'\0');` appears to be wrong, what you might want is `memset(a,'\0', 100);` but that will also be wrong, as you'll be exceeding the allocated size anyway.
- For a hosted environment, the signature for `main()` is `int main(void)` at least to be conforming to the standard.
- Always check for the success of `malloc()` before using the returned pointer.